# PHP Regular expressions problem

Tags: php

I'm using regex to pull info from a html **table**.

But I'm messing up some how, and have no idea why.

**PHP CODE:**

```
$printable = file_get_contents('./testplaylist.php', true);

if(preg_match_all('/<TR[^>]*>(.*?)<\/TR>/si', $printable, $matches, PREG_SET_ORDER)); {
foreach($matches as $match) {
$data = "$match[1]";

echo("$data <br />");

}
}
```

**HTML DATA:**

```
<TR class=" light ">
Stuff in here
</TR>
```

Any help would be appreciated,

Thanks!

Comment: *(related)* [Best Methods to parse HTML](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3577641/best-methods-to-parse-html/3577662#3577662)

Comment: _(related)_ [Best methods to parse HTML with PHP](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3577641/best-methods-to-parse-html-with-php)

Comment: also, since the extension is `.php`. Is the HTML snippet you show actually in that file or will the PHP file generate it when executed. In the latter case, you have to `file_get_contents` from a webserver.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this one instead

http://sandbox.phpcode.eu/g/bba70.php

```
if(preg_match_all('/<TR[^>]*>(.*?)<\/TR>/msU', $printable, $matches)) {  
     foreach($matches[1] as $match) {
          echo("$match <br />");   
      }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I know what your first problem is. regex! I kid! but have you checked out PHP DOM?

http://www.php.net/manual/en/domdocument.loadhtmlfile.php

It would probably work in your case just fine. It would be 10x easier too.

> Some people, when confronted with a problem, think “I know, I'll use
>   regular expressions.”   Now they have two problems. -Jamie Zawinski

Answer (score 0):

Works fine here. It should work unless you have nested tables.

The problem must be in your data source. Do some tracing with `var_dump`.

Answer (score 0):

Use PHP's document object model to be safe when parsing HTML. Except for very simple regexes, HTML parsing rapidly gets out of control when you DIY. There's a bit of overhead to set it up, but once you get going it's straightforward.

See [DOM](http://php.net/manual/en/book.dom.php) for instructions on how to use it.

If you stick to the regex technique, at the least, you may need to escape all '<' and '>'s eg.

```
/\<TR[^>]*\>(.*?)\<\/TR\>/si
```

Comment: no, `<` `>` has no special meaning in regex.

Comment: Yes avoid regexes like the plague. Then, if you *have* to use regexes at least escape the angled brackets, or better yet: quote litteral parts of your pattern. E.g.: `$pattern = '/\\Q<TR\\E[^>*]\\>(.*?)\\Q</TR>\\E/si';`

Comment: @yi_H: On the contrary, `<` and `>` do have special meaning in PHP interpretation of Perl regexes which is what the preg module provides. They allow you to name subpatterns: (?P<name>sub_pattern).

Comment: uhm.. no. `?'name'` is also a named subpattern. But you normally don't escape `'`, right? You only have to escape where it would be missinterpreted.